# Is there a faster way to insert dataframe to SQL using python?

Tags: python, sql-server, azure

We have two parts to get final data frame into SQL.

1. downlaoding from datasets from Azure and transforming using python.
2. Uploading transformed data into Azure and then inserting the final dataframe into SQL

Downloading, transforming and uploading takes 5 mins but insertion to SQL is taking quite long time. I used below code for faster insertion.

```
server = 'XXXX.database.windows.net' 
database = 'XXX' 
username = 'XXX' 
password = 'XXXX' 
driver= '{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)



params = urllib.parse.quote_plus('DRIVER='+driver+
                      ';SERVER='+server+
                      ';PORT=1433;DATABASE='+database+
                      ';UID='+username+
                      ';PWD='+ password)
    
engine = 
sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params),fast_executemany=True)
conn = engine.connect()



with engine.connect() as connection:
    
    try:  
      
         df_copy.to_sql('XXXX',connection,if_exists = 'append',index=False,chunksize=500)

    except SQLAlchemyError as e:
     error = str(e.__dict__['orig'])
     print(error)
    

conn.close()
```

Final data frame contains 97000 rows with 127 columns.

SQL Server configuration : Purchased Azure SQL 10 DTUS 250GB of storage.

The error is

> Exception has occurred: OperationalError
> (pyodbc.OperationalError) ('08S01', '[08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.\r\n (10054) (SQLExecute); [08S01] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Communication link failure (10054)')

I have also used `connect_args={'connect_timeout': 2400}` inside create engine but after 40-50 mins we are receiving the same error mgs. I think 50 mins for 97k records is quite long time.
Any way I could improve the process ? Also, I'm currently running on my local machine which has 16GB ram and 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1265U   1.80 GHz processor. Also, we use Jenkins for deployment. Will there be any faster performance if we test it on Jenkins?

Comment: Is the `chunksize` the number of rows?

Comment: Sorry @J.D. for the late reply. Yes it is the no of rows to insert at once.

Comment: A couple questions: 
1.Have you tried uploading different sizes of the dataframe? Maybe cut it to 5k, 10k, 25k, etc... to see where the breaking point is? 
2. this is a decent sized dataset for a 10DTU server (especially if the columns are hefty i.e. binary image data or massive xml payloads), did you look at the resource utilization on the azure sql database? If you have access to the azure portal, you can see the CPU/Memory utilization by going to "Metrics" under "Monitoring". Have you tried scaling it up to see if that has any affect?

Comment: The error occured because you already opened the connection, you can't have two connections. After you created your `engine`, you called the connect method, `conn = engine.connect()`. However, afterwards you try to open it again with a conext manager, that is `with engine.connect() ...`

Answer (score 0):

hello there  you should try to specify your chunksize in your call
df.to_sql(engine, connect() , index=False, if_exists='append',
method=None, chunksize = 50000)

Comment: i have tried with different chunksize's i.e 500,1000 & 2000  and its already in the code but it doesn't improve any performance.

Comment: @aredlarevanthreddy The chunk sizes you're trying are quite small. You should be doing at least 10,000 rows at a time. I'd recommend trying 10k, 25k, 50k, and 100k and see which one works the best. SQL Server is good at inserting in bulk (to a degree). There's downtime with such small chunk sizes that you tried.